# Type 'ASP._Page_index_cshtml' does not inherit from 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPage'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I am getting:

> Type 'ASP._Page_index_cshtml' does not inherit from 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPage'.

when I browse to my index.cshtml file.  It is very simple:

```
@using System.Web.Optimization
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Hello World</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css", "~/Content/themes/base/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    @Scripts.Render(
        "~/bundles/jquery",
        "~/bundles/jqueryui"
    )
</body>
</html>
```

my index.cshtml file is outside of the Views folder, if that matters at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had to remove: `@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage`

Looks like I had a copy paste error when reorganizing my project.

Comment: This is not the solution, is actually causing another problem, you have an extra file that is hidden in the project.. See my answer please.

Answer (score 3):

Do not remove the inheritance, it might be necesary and might lead to another problems in the future.

Instead try this:

Enable "View all Files" in the web project that is failing, and search for a file that seems correct but is not included in visual studio, and delete it. If it fails in your deployment folder, try to clean the folder as well, and re-deploy the site, you might have unnecesary files that might cause the same problem.

In my case, at the root of the webproject I had an extra copy of _ViewStart.cshtml (excluded from the project), I deleted that file, and that did the trick.

Hope it helps, let me know if this solve your problem as well.

Comment: Exactly what happened to me. I had an erronous FTP upload where I put _ViewStart.cshtml in the root of the directory and not in /Views/. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This helped me too. In my case, I had accidentally moved web.config from my Views folder to the Home folder beneath it. When I moved it back the application started working again.

Answer (score 2):

I change the cshtml line from:

```
Layout = "~/Views/_ViewStart.cshtml";
```

to

```
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
```

since _ViewStart.cshtml contains only that line of code. Layout file was required because it contains the script to client-side validation.

It worked also when I remove the line, but I prefer to keep `_Layout.cshtml` included.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to add...

```cshtml
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.ViewStartPage
```

...to the top of `_ViewStart.cshtml`.

I think the reason this worked for me was because of my `~/Views/Web.config` file.  In it I had placed the following block in order to avoid a bunch of `@inherits` calls on my views...

```xml
<configuration>
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage"> <!-- Notice pageBaseType -->
      ...
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
</configuration>
```

I think this instructed the razor engine that all views including `_ViewStart.cshtml` were to be of type `System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage`.  This is not the same type as `System.Web.Mvc.ViewSTartPage` and hence the error.  Putting `@inherits System.Web.Mvc.ViewStartPage` at the start of `_ViewStart.cshtml` explicitly specifies the required type for `_ViewStart.cshtml`.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that an older version of System.Web.WebPages.dll is loaded to memory, and it tries to cast the your cshtml page to a version of WebPages class from that dll.

To test this, try to see what http modules are currently registered:

```
var allModules = HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.Modules;
for( int i = 0; i < allModules.Count; i++ ) {
    Trace(allModules.GetKey(i));
}
```

In my case that was:

```
....
__DynamicModule_System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpModule, System.Web.WebPages, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35_bca8e05a-5746-45b0-be95-2b920b455ccf

__DynamicModule_System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpModule, System.Web.WebPages, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35_c1a67b42-31a9-47f1-8483-9e712fabe2a7
```

To fix the problem you need to replace the older version of System.Web.WebPages.dll in your /Bin folders, or some other dll-s that might be referencing it.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the _ViewStart.cshtml and re-add.

Answer (score 0):

No need to take Tension. Just follow 2 basic steps

1. Delete the `_ViewStart.cshtml`
2. Make statement to a comment. Means for the following statement in index view:

   ```
   Layout = "~/Views/_ViewStart.cshtml";
   ```

   and mark it as a comment:

   ```
   //Layout = "~/Views/_ViewStart.cshtml";
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Comment Layout variable in your .cshtml file

```
//Layout = "~/Views/_ViewStart.cshtml";
```

Answer (score -1):

Why are you trying to browse directly to a view?  And why isn't it in a views folder?

To get a basic "Hello World" page up you first want to create a controller called `HomeController.cs`:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Then create a file `/Views/Home/Index.cshtml` and put your markup in that.  You may also need to add:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
 }
```

to the top of the page since it doesn't look like you are using a master page.

As a side note, all this assumes you haven't screwed with your default routing.

Comment: Looking through your comment history, it doesn't look like you are an MVC beginner which I assumed when I posted this.  So I apologize if this post comes across as condescending.  I don't think the server is going to be able to render a view correctly if it's not routed through a controller though.  When you say return View(); that's where the rendering actually happens and it's an important step that I don't think you can skip.

Answer (score -4):

Remove the web.config from your Views folder.

As you're including Partial1.cshtml from that folder, it is also including the web.config from within there. And that web.config is saying that all pages must inherit from WebViewPage.